# ExoPlayer did not played mp4 video

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am stuck to play mp4 video on exoplayer yet exoplayer only run mpd
videos only please help me to resolve this issue.

when i pass .mpd format videos player will play smoothly and in case of mp4 player stuck to play

```
 lateinit var mDailyWorkOutShowCatResponseList: ArrayList<DailyWorkOutShowCatResponse>
        private lateinit var simpleExoplayer: SimpleExoPlayer
        private var playbackPosition = 0L
        private val dashUrl = "http://rdmedia.bbc.co.uk/dash/ondemand/bbb/2/client_manifest-separate_init.mpd"
        private val bandwidthMeter by lazy {
            DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        }
        private val adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory by lazy {
            AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        }

        var mUrlStr:String = "http://rdmedia.bbc.co.uk/dash/ondemand/bbb/2/client_manifest-separate_init.mpd"


        fun videoPrepareImplementation(urlStr:String) {


            initializeExoplayer(urlStr)
        }

        override fun getDailyWorkByCategoryOutResponse(dailyWorkOutShowCatResponselist: ArrayList<DailyWorkOutShowCatResponse>) {

            videoPrepareImplementation(mUrlStr)

        }
        override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
            if (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING)
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY)
                progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } 
        private fun initializeExoplayer(urlStr: String) {
            simpleExoplayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
                DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory),
                DefaultLoadControl()
            )

            prepareExoplayer(urlStr)
            simpleExoPlayerView.player = simpleExoplayer
            simpleExoplayer.seekTo(playbackPosition)
            simpleExoplayer.playWhenReady = true
            simpleExoplayer.addListener(this)
        }

        private fun releaseExoplayer() {
            playbackPosition = simpleExoplayer.currentPosition
            simpleExoplayer.release()
        }

        private fun buildMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource {
            val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua", bandwidthMeter)
            val dashChunkSourceFactory = DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            return DashMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, dashChunkSourceFactory, null, null)
        }

        private fun prepareExoplayer(urlStr: String) {
            val uri = Uri.parse(urlStr)
            val mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri)
            simpleExoplayer.prepare(mediaSource)
        }
```

kinldy help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

just use ProgressiveMediaSource and buildMediaSource function will be like

```
private fun buildMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource { 
val dataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua", bandwidthMeter) 
return ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri) 
}
```

and it will play

Answer (score -1):

According to the code lab and according to my experience it should work. Just check this code lab:- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

In this code lab mp3,mp4, and dash URL is working fine

Comment: that exoplayer libaray have min sdk is 26 i want to get 18 min

Comment: did not helpful